# Elasticsearch with HTTPS POST/PUT/GET request

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any document available to setup Elasticsearch to serve connection over SSL ?. And is the option available on ELS ?.

Ex :  curl -XGET https://localhost:9200/

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/_configure_the_keystores_and_enable_ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your code to call SSL. What language are you using? Are you using a custom client or one provided by ElasticSearch ([Find a list of clients supplied by ElasticSearch here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html))? If you are using a client you can configure them to use SSL ([Here is an example for PHP's client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_configuration.html)).

I use SSL by using PHP's curl library. I do not use an clients, but instead a custom client. The following will list the stats of ElasticSearch from an SSL connection.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://localhost:9200/_stats');
curl_exec($ch); // this outputs to the browser. 
// You can capture it using PHP's output buffer 
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I'm using python to post the data directly into the ELS. Not sure if I do https post from my python,then how ELS do SSL offload. As I haven't done any configuration part to support SSL by ELS. When reading the article, it says "ELS is plain [ http ]".

Comment: @KMG Try configuring it and let me know if that worked. I supplied the link for PHP in my answer above.